# Firebase database cant retrieve my list with dataSnapshot(cant convert object)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 public void retriveData(){
                databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        Log.e("Count " ,""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Info post=new Info();
                            Log.e("EEEERRRORRR", "onChildAdded: "+postSnapshot.toString() );
                            Info post=postSnapshot.getValue(Info.class);
                            Log.e("Get Data", post.getQuestion());
                        }
                    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.sahilliolu.rqagame, PID: 3006
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.sahilliolu.rqagame.Info
```

Everything works fine until setQuestion(). I get the correctChildrenCont in log.e. How can I fix this? For more reference I am pasting my Info class which is a simple class that has string arguments in its constructor

```
public class Info {
    public String answer,question,a,b,c,d;


    public Info(String question,String answer,String a,String b,String c,String d){
        this.question=question;
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
        this.c=c;
        this.d=d;
        this.answer=answer;
    }
    public Info(){

    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create object using datasnapshot of required class like

```
 ClassName post = postSnapshot.getValue(ClassName.class);
```

and your class should contain same variables as they are in database

ex your database contains two columns Name and Age

then your Class should contain Name and Age as variable and you should create getter, setter and constructor

By getting data using this method your data(questions) will already be setted to your variables.

see this 
[for more info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: I did all the things you say but I still get the same error about converting  For more reference I am updating the code and adding the Info class

Comment: I think your databaseReference is pointing to wrong location which consisting only one node(String) you should make sure it should point to location which consists answer,question,a,b,c,d and keep case & name of variables exactly to the nodes which present in database .

Comment: @Freshia, I think you should edit your question and include your Firebase Database structure (in json format if possible)